# $ G/N$ has an element of order $m$ so, $G$ also has an element of order $m$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I swear to God, I've done about a trillion of these sorts of problems and I still don't know how to prove them. Is it as easy as saying that $G/N$ is a subgroup of $G$, and therefore $G$ contains this element of $m$? Of course it's not that simple.

Comment: But $G/N$ is not a subgroup of $G$. Hint: There is an element in $G$ with order a multiple of $m$.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that |G|=|G/N|*|N|, so an element m in G/N is an element m*n in G (with n being in N). But that's m*n, not m.

Comment: Recall that the elements of $G/N$ have the form $gN$ for $g\in G$. Write up what it means that such an element has order $m$ in $G/N$ (ie, what it says about $g$).

Comment: It means that (gN)^m = N. Therefore, N contains an element of m, and then g contains an element of m? Close?

Comment: No. $N$ need not contain an element of order $m$ ($N$ could be the trivial subgroup for all we know).

Comment: How is the multiplication of those cosets defined?

Comment: so g multiplies every element of N. So if there is an element m in G/N, there exists an element of order m/|g| in N?

Comment: Please look up how the multiplication is defined in the group $G/N$.

Comment: I've been reading about the quotient group all day, actually, and I'm still having troubles comprehending it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group#Definition I'm looking at this example. Pattern: order of g=0 is 1, order of elements in N are 1 and 2, result of the element in G/N = 2. Then order of g=1 is 6, elements of N are 1 and 2, result in G/N is 6. Order of g=2 is 3, result in G/N is of order 6. So it's a least common multiple deal, right?

Comment: The problem is clearly false if $G$ is not assumed to be finite, by virtue of $G = \mathbb{Z}$ and $N = m \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G/N$ has an element of order $m$. This means there is an equivalence class $gN$ with the property that if you multiply it by itself $m$ times, you get the equivalence class $N$. So $g^mN=N$, which implies $g^m\in N$ and $g^k \notin N$ for $k < m$. In particular, for such $k$, $g^k$ is not the identity, so the order of $g$ is at least $m$. In fact, it must be a multiple of $m$, since otherwise dividing the order by $m$ and looking at the remainder would contradict $g^k \neq e$ (the identity) for $k < m$.

Write the order of $g$ in $G$ as $mn$ for some $n\ge1$. Then $G$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $mn$. Knowing the structure of subgroups of cyclic groups, we know that $G$ also has to have a subgroup of order $m$, and we're done.

Comment: This reasoning is clearly false, one can only say that $o(g^k)$ *divides* $m$. Here is a counterexample: $S_3/A_3$ has order $2$ but $A_3$ does not have an element of order $2$. Or: $A_4/V_4$ has order $3$, but $V_4$ does not have elements of order $3$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Indeed. Thanks for spotting that. I fixed it.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the fact $o(g)=mn$, or more generally $o(gN)| o(g)$ can be proved this way too. We know that there’s a homomorphism from $G$ to $G/N$, that is $\pi(g)=gN$. Now by some elementary corollaries, we see that $o(gN)=o(\pi(g))| o(g)$. This is a very useful lemma in recent papers on the order of the elements. And we see that it was the key to prove this statement.